# SiteMinder web agent freeze with apached 2.4 (32bit) on Windows 2012 64

Tags: windows-server-2012, apache-2.4, single-sign-on

I am using Apached with Siteminder for single-sign on authentication. My config is as follow:

64 bit Windows 2012 (64) R1. 
Apached 2.4, (32 bits) (We tried the 64 bits but it does not work with the siteminder agent, dll problem). It was downloaded from apache lounge

The problem i am facing today is that every hour the webagent freeze, and the authentication does not work until i restart apache.

Apache is used as a reverse proxy for Tomcat. The tomcat service runs well, no problem. But then i have to restart my apache all the time to keep the service on tomcat running properly.

My question is:

- has anyone ever experience a similar issue, where the SiteMinder web-agent somewhat freeze every now and then stopping the authentication service ? If yes, what did you do to solve it ?
- Is there a way to integrate SiteMinder to Tomcat directly? Is it recommended ? What can be the consequence of it ? Does the integration works with Tomcat 8 ?
- Is there any known issue between Siteminder and Windows 2012 ?

Best,

M